# Is there a standardized practice for ordering attributes in HTML tags?

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, html

I am working on an AngularJS project and the attributes are numerous in many of my HTML elements:

```
  <button type="submit" 
          ng-click="Page.UI.DetailView.ExecuteFunction()" 
          ng-disabled="step5.$invalid" 
          class="btn btn-success pull-right">
      Submit this Product
  </button>
```

Is there a standardized convention for the order of these attributes?  Alphabetical? Grouped by meaning (e.g. all angular attributes together)?  Standard HTML attributes ("type" for example) first?

Comment: No, there's no standard.  W3C says that the order of attributes does not matter.  Find some Angular code examples somewhere on the Internet or in an Angular book, and follow whatever convention they've set there; chances are it's close to "correct," if not actually "correct."

Comment: I dont think so. But if you look at the dom in console it is alphabetically ordered.

Comment: In addition, you can find loads of advice by Googling "Ordering attributes in HTML tags."

Comment: Thanks AbelD and @RobertHarvey.  I am indeed finding plenty of opinions via Google, but was hoping that there is a more standard approach.  Thanks again.

Comment: @AbelD Alphabetical ordering of HTML attributes sounds like the worst idea ever though, for a developer.

Comment: @Alternatex I did not ask anyone to do alphabetical order. I said thats how it is displayed.

Comment: Weeeell, you _could_ shave of whole micro-seconds of processing time by putting `ng-if` first ;-)    Hmmm, seriously, maybe put `ng-` at the end, as they may override previous tags?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no standard. Optimize for ease of understanding, and try to be consistent.

Personally I think it's also good to always put the `id` attribute first, so that it's easier for testers to find it.

Comment: I find the most important thing is to be concise. If working in a team, make sure you follow the same pattern for the aforementioned reason. I tend to stick to `type`, `id`/`for`, `name`, `class`. If I'm using angular then all `ng-`-attributes will go first. It's down to personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

> Use **class** >> **id** >> **style**, in this order.

I am developing a framework, and it generates html code as one of it's functionalities.

For example you can create a div using `html($attributes)`

- You can use the `$attributes` as a string like `id="one" class="two"` or simply `two` (to be converted into `class="two"`);
- You can use the `$attributes` as an array like `['data-target' => 'test', 'style' => 'margin: 0;']` or simply `['class1 class2', 'myId', 'padding: 1em;']` to be converted to `['class' => 'class1 class2', 'id' => 'myId', 'style' => 'padding: 1em;']`.

**Why?**

Because `class`, `id` and `style` are the most used attributes in tags, in this order, and they are universal. You can use them in every tag inside html's `<body>`, not like `href`, `name`, `readonly` and other attributes that are used in only a short range of html tags.